# Spring OAuth2 - How does the authorization server handle the Security Context with two instances of a client?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently working on a scenario of two instances of a OAuth2 Spring Client (**A** and **B**) contacting the same AuthorizationServer (**C**). When using two windows on Chrome, one normal and one in Incognito mode this works fine.

Both **A** and **B** contact **C**, and I can login with two different accounts, and the user endpoint returns the correct Principal with the given user.

However, if I switch the client in the same browser window from **A**, and call the login path on **B**, the login screen is not prompted, and I am instantly logged in as the same user that was in the window for **A**, on **B**.

I have checked if this was due to cookies, but it seems that is not the case. I am not able to understand how **B** that does not communicate with **A** know to send the correct token and retrieve the security data fomr **C** that was connected to **A**. I have tried this both on Incognito and normal, both times the other principal was returned.

In summary my question is this: How does **B** send data connected to the login process of **A** and **C** and vice versa while in the same browser session?

Comment: The clients are both written in Java using Spring Framework. I am using `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and a custom implementation of `ResourceServerTokenServices`

Comment: I have figured out that indeed there is a `JSESSIONID` being created during the communication. Once I switched the cookie and tried the login, I switched the user. I missed this because other parts of our application creates this cookie as well, and figured it was just that other cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I switch the client in the same browser window from A, and
>   call the login path on B, the login screen is not prompted, and I am
>   instantly logged in as the same user that was in the window for A, on
>   B.

Frankly this is because there is no relationship between the access_token generated and client credentials (Used to identify clients, in your differentiate whether login request coming from A or B) when you login. It only matters while generating the access_token.

In a simple case where a User X requests an OAuth2 Bearer access_token via a Web Site and an Iphone will result in 2 unique access_token being generated and being persisted in the server backend.

If somehow User X gets the access_token generated in the Web Site and uses it in the Header

```
Authorization: Bearer <Website Generated access_token>
```

While calling the Protected Endpoint, the User X will not an 401 or 403 because the access_token sent is actually available in the Backend server. Only validations like whether the access_token is still valid (Not expired will be performed).

Comment: Mhm, this makes sense. Only one thing that I can't understand now is, how does B, when accessed in the same windows as A was, but was not accessed before, get the access_token? Is it stored somewhere within the browser session? I have looked into the spring library in the meantime and have seen that the logic for the refreshing of token works without issue. It is only the first time that is confusing.

Comment: No, I am using `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` `ResourceServerTokenServices` ( a custom implementation) from the Spring OAuth2 library.